# The entity type [entity name] does not have an "revision_created" entity revision metadata key

Tags: entity, metadata, drupal-9

I am using Drupal 9.0.5 as recommends Drupal site.
I created a first entity content type, but I got the message "The entity type [entity name] does not have an "revision_created" entity revision metadata key.".

Comment: If this is a question, then it is a very strange one.

Comment: It is a issue, with the solution. A information for guys like me who would have been blocked.

Comment: @Jaskin, Please add the solution for your problem as an answer

Comment: This worked for me in `@[EntityType]Entity` rather than `@ContentEntityType`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer that was added into the question originally:

I solved this problem by adding this in my entity file (in @ContentEntityType) :

```
 * revision_metadata_keys = {
 *     "revision_user" = "revision_user",
 *     "revision_created" = "revision_created",
 *     "revision_log_message" = "revision_log"
 *   },
```

Perhaps that could help somebody.